# How to get Data of Accelerometer using spen remote sdk

Tags: samsung-galaxy, samsung-mobile-sdk, stylus-pen

this says The Note10 S Pen has both gyroscope and accelerometer sensors, which provide moving coordinates to the phone.
but in spen remote sdk, I could see only deltaX and deltaY values, not Z index or accelerometer data.
I want use accelerometer data to make custom gestures in android app. anyone can help me how do I get x,y, and Z index of spen or accelerometer data ?

[https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-spen-remote/overview.html#:~:text=The%20Note10%20S%20Pen%20has%20both%20gyroscope%20and%20accelerometer%20sensors%2C%20which%20provide%20moving%20coordinates%20to%20the%20phone](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-spen-remote/overview.html#:%7E:text=The%20Note10%20S%20Pen%20has%20both%20gyroscope%20and%20accelerometer%20sensors%2C%20which%20provide%20moving%20coordinates%20to%20the%20phone)